# ABI stability: When do I break ABI?

Tags: c++, c

In short: When do I break ABIs while working at larger C/C++ libraries, that have consumers and are expecting stability throughout non-major releases?

Comment: Too broad, What does it mean 'used privately'? Was it a member of publicly available class?

Comment: I can remove it also. It's not important for the question too much. Same would apply for function additions.

Comment: This is a subjective question, each situation may have a different answer. If the business needs are too great to break ABI due to maintenance issues, then maybe now is not the right time to break ABI. If the business needs justify it, then maybe now is the right time. It really depends on the situation

Comment: No, it is important. Altering a publicly available class in any way (adding, modifying or removing any members of it regardless of their access modifier), changing access level of said members, etc, does break ABI.

Comment: This then touches the core of the question and the answer would be yes, meaning API changes are necessarily ABI changes.

Comment: Addressed your point in the question.

Comment: @SteveLorimer I believe you have misinterpreted the question. It seems to me that it's not about when it's OK to break ABI, but rather, what changes can break ABI. The title and the fist paragraph could be less ambiguous. I could be wrong myself though, in which case the second paragraph seems unrelated to the question.

Comment: @user2079303 yeah, I see what he meant now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's a difference between API and ABI incompatibility. API incompatibility refers to deprecating/removing a function as you said that users can no longer use in a new library. This will make old code not compile.

ABI incompatibility on the other hand includes instability/linking errors, such if a library was compiled on a System V versus ARM system, or compiled with libstdc++ or libc++. This requires that the entire library be recompiled for the target system.

Comment: Is API incompatibility a subset of ABI incompatibility then? Imagine the case that users haven't used a a publicly available function, so theoretically code should compile, I assume. In any case the answer would be sufficient to me.

Comment: @eljefedelrodeodeljefe _"Is API incompatibility a subset of ABI incompatibility then?"_ They are orthogonal things.

Comment: @eljefedelrodeodeljefe if you have a public function, then you cannot guarantee that users haven't used it (unless you fully control your users, in which case why care about ABI, when you could simply have your controlled users re-compile their code). Some API changes (such as removal of a public function) do break ABI. Some API changes don't necessarily.

Comment: Okay. That makes it complete then. As a reference, the question was rather "academic". In the case I am thinking of I will never be able to remove the function no matter if it breaks ABI or not. Thanks for all the info.